# Error message for spec: undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm trying to write a spec that will test whether users with the role "premium" can edit wikis with the attribute "personal."

Here is one of my scenarios (this is a feature spec)

```
scenario "it allows premium users to assign collaborators" do
    user = create(:user, role: 'premium')
    wiki = create(:wiki, personal: true)
    r = create(:relationship, wiki_id: wiki.id, user_id: user.id, creator_created: true)
    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    visit (edit_wiki_path(wiki))
    expect(page).to have_content('Private')
    expect(page).to have_content("Select collaborators")
end
```

The error message I get is,

```
Failure/Error: click_on('Edit')
ActionView::Template::Error:
  undefined local variable or method `wiki' for #<#<Class:0xb22e920>:0xcb58c0c>
```

When I try to go through all the steps a user would go through, I get the same error message, so it's not just a problem with the visit method . . . here's an example:

```
  scenario "it allows premium users to edit Private Wikis" do
    wiki = create(:wiki, personal: true)
    user = create(:user, role: 'premium')
    r = create(:relationship, wiki_id: wiki.id, user_id: user.id, creator_created: true)
    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    visit root_path
    click_on('View Private Wikis')
    click_on('MyString') # the title of the wiki created above
    click_on('Edit')
    click_button('Save and Parse')
    expect(page).to have_content('MyString')
  end
```

Here, the error message reads,

```
Failure/Error: click_on('Edit')
ActionView::Template::Error:
  undefined local variable or method `wiki' for #<#<Class:0xb22e920>:0xcb58c0c>
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ellen, please add the full error stack trace (with line numbers if available) and the contents of the view template file that's intended to be rendered when clicking on Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out I had a typo in my controller, referring to @wiki as wiki. Fixed that and hey, the problem went away!